# Drawing clock face in Mathematica (looking for a better solution)

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica, drawing, clock

I am trying to find a general solution for drawing clock face like graphical objects in Mathematica. I've already implemented a version of my own, but I think a much better solution must exist. A neater version with less code or clearer thought process would be appreciated.

My version:

```
radius = 1;
elementList = 
  Join[Table[i, {i, 3, 1, -1}], Table[i, {i, 12, 4, -1}]];
elementNumber = Length[elementList];
thetaList = Table[i, {i, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/elementNumber}][[1 ;; 12]];
coordinateList = Map[{radius*Cos[#], radius*Sin[#]} &, thetaList];
objectList = 
  Map[Style[#, FontFamily -> "Georgia", FontSize -> 30] &, 
   elementList];
Graphics[
 Join[
  MapThread[Text[#1, #2] &, {objectList, coordinateList}],
  {Circle[{0, 0}, 1.2*radius]}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this would be a good starting point: http://blog.wolfram.com/2007/07/09/always-the-right-time-for-mathematica/

Comment: I think the suggestion from @BrettChampion answers this question perfectly. I feel a little ashamed about asking this (I should ask both Google and the documentation before I ask question here, and I did only the later). Should I keep this post or delete it, which choice would be better for the community?

Comment: I would keep your post. There are lots of interesting ways to construct clocks (and clock faces).

Comment: @Ning IMHO, as somebody who's learning Mathematica and working with it daily, I say keep it. The two answers below are interesting and I enjoy learning from seeing how other people approach these sorts of questions (i.e. two very different answers).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way to make a clock:

```
clockFace = Import["http://i.imgur.com/ufanv.jpg"];
{hour, minute, second} = Take[Date[], -3];
hour = Mod[hour, 12] + minute/60.; 
Graphics3D[
{
 {Texture[clockFace], 
      Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}},
         VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}
      ]
 }, 
 {Black, AbsoluteThickness[8], 
      Line[{{0, 0, 0}, 
       .55 {Cos[Pi/2 - 2 Pi hour/12], Sin[Pi/2 - 2 Pi hour/12], 0}}
      ]
 },
 {Black, AbsoluteThickness[5], 
      Line[{{0, 0, 0}, 
       .8 {Cos[Pi/2 - 2 Pi minute/60], Sin[Pi/2 - 2 Pi minute/60], 0}}
      ]
 }
}, 
Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: a clock with a nice face generated by Mathematica]

**Addition**

Here is a rotating, spinning 3D clock for your amusement:

```
clockFace = Import["http://i.imgur.com/ufanv.jpg"];
vtc = VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
hand[thickness_, radius_, time_] := {AbsoluteThickness[thickness],
   Line[{{0, 0, -1}, {radius Cos[Pi/2 + 2 Pi time],
      radius Sin[Pi/2 + 2 Pi time], -1}}],
   Line[{{0, 0, 1}, {radius Cos[Pi/2 - 2 Pi time],
      radius Sin[Pi/2 - 2 Pi time], 1}}],
   Line[{{0, -1, 0}, {radius Cos[Pi/2 - 2 Pi time], -1,
      radius Sin[Pi/2 - 2 Pi time]}}],
   Line[{{0, 1, 0}, {radius Cos[Pi/2 + 2 Pi time], 1,
      radius Sin[Pi/2 + 2 Pi time]}}],
   Line[{{-1, 0, 0}, {-1, radius Cos[Pi/2 + 2 Pi time],
      radius Sin[Pi/2 + 2 Pi time]}}],
   Line[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, radius Cos[Pi/2 - 2 Pi time],
      radius Sin[Pi/2 - 2 Pi time]}}]};
Dynamic[
  {hour, minute, second} = Take[Date[], -3];
  hour = Mod[hour, 12] + minute/60.;
  Graphics3D[{
    {Texture[clockFace],
     Polygon[{{1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}},
      vtc],
     Polygon[{{-1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}, vtc],
     Polygon[{{-1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}},
      vtc], Polygon[{{1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}},
      vtc], Polygon[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}, {-1, -1,
        1}}, vtc],
     Polygon[{{1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, vtc]
     }, {Black,
     hand[8, .55, hour/12],
     hand[5, .8, minute/60],
     hand[3, .8, second/60]
     }
    },
   Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral",
   ViewPoint ->
    5 {Cos[2 Pi second/60], Sin[2 Pi second/60],
      Sin[2 Pi second/30]}, SphericalRegion -> True,
Background -> Black, ImageSize -> Full]] // Deploy
```

[image: 3D clock]

Comment: Perhaps you could use something like `Polygon[#, vtc] & /@(PolyhedronData["Cube", "VertexCoordinates"][[#]] & /@ 
   PolyhedronData["Cube", "FaceIndices"])]` to get the faces coords

Comment: @belisarius, that is a good tip, but I have to individually adjust the polygons to make the ones on the sides be upright.

Comment: yep. I was wondering if that can be fixed with a permutation. I didn't try very hard, but could not find an obvious way.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version of a function that generalizes the generation of clock face to allow you to easily change the style of the numbers, the number of "hours", and the radius of the face:

```
Options[clockFace] = {FontFamily -> "Georgia", FontSize -> 30};
clockFace[hours_Integer, radius_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] /;
   hours > 0 && Im[radius] == 0 && radius > 0 :=
 With[{range = Range[12]},
  With[{objects = 
        Style[#, 
          FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Style]] ~Join~ Options[clockFace]] & /@ range,
       thetas = Pi/2 - 2 Pi*range/hours},
  Graphics[Append[
     MapThread[Text[#1, {Cos[#2], Sin[#2]}] &, {objects, thetas}],
     Circle[radius*1.2]]]]]
```

Some things are just Mathematica style issues; for instance,

```
FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Style]] ~Join~ Options[clockFace]
```

is just the way to pass the relevant optional arguments to `Style` while making sure that `clockFace`'s default values are used where relevant, because Mathematica will use the first applicable rule that it finds in a list of rules (and function options are just lists of rules). I also used `With` to name things, which is why there's that nesting; other people might prefer to use a single `Module`. Either way, it's always best to make things local variables whenever possible.

The biggest change, though, was generating the list of numbers in order, using `Range`, and then adjusting the definition of `thetas` so everything winds up in the right place. I think it's much easier to see what's going on, because the minus sign means you're moving around clockwise and offsetting by `Pi/2` makes it clear you're starting at the top of the clock.

Answer (score 5):

The following is a **working 3D clock** made by easily combining @Arnoud's answer with [Christopher's blog entry](http://blog.wolfram.com/2007/07/09/always-the-right-time-for-mathematica/):

```
makeHand[fl_, bl_, fw_, bw_] :=
    Polygon[{{-bw, -bl, 0.1}, {bw, -bl, 0.1}, {fw, fl, 0.1}, 
             {0, fl + 8 fw, 0.1}, {-fw, fl, 0.1}}/9];

hourHand = makeHand[5, 5/3, .1, .3];
minuteHand = makeHand[7, 7/3, .1, .3];
secondHand = {Red, EdgeForm[Black], makeHand[7, 7/3, .1/2, .3/2]};
clockFace = Import["http://i.imgur.com/ufanv.jpg"];

Graphics3D[{
  {Texture[clockFace], 
   Polygon[{{-1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]},

    Rotate[hourHand, Dynamic[Refresh[-30 Mod[AbsoluteTime[]/3600, 60] \[Degree], 
     UpdateInterval -> 60]], {0, 0, 1}],
    Rotate[minuteHand, Dynamic[Refresh[-6 Mod[AbsoluteTime[]/60, 60] \[Degree], 
     UpdateInterval -> 1]], {0, 0, 1}],
    Rotate[secondHand, Dynamic[Refresh[-6 Mod[AbsoluteTime[], 60] \[Degree], 
     UpdateInterval -> 1/20]], {0, 0, 1}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

**Edit**

The animation was captured by using Rasterize[] inside a  scheduled task!

```
a = Graphics3D[(* etc etc*)];
b = {};
t = CreateScheduledTask[AppendTo[b, Rasterize@a], {2, 30}];
StartScheduledTask[t];
While[MatchQ[ScheduledTasks[], {ScheduledTaskObject[_, _, _, _,True]}],Pause[1]];
RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]];
Export["c:\\test.gif", b, "DisplayDurations" -> 1]
```

Comment: +1, okay. that is just kind of wrong. I even downloaded v8 so I could run it.

Comment: @rcollyer I am afraid I don't understand. What is wrong there?

Comment: sorry, colloquialism. The [third definition](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wrong) from the urban dictionary is closest to my usage here. Specifically, I was commenting on the irony of using a very powerful tool to create an accurate clock animation.

Comment: @rcollyer Did you notice the use of `ScheduledTask` in the last edit? I never used it like that before!

Comment: No, I hadn't. Wow, and I thought the first use was absurd. This one is worse, and funnier for it.

Answer (score 5):

*Mathematica* has something called [`ClockGauge`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClockGauge.html) built-in. The possibilities for styling the clock face are endless, as can be seen in the documentation. The bare-bone version looks like this:

```
ClockGauge[]
```

[image: Clock gauge]

Comment: Please take a look a the time-stamp in the question :)

Comment: @belisarius Oh well, it can't hurt to have this solution here as well.

Comment: I guess almost all questions about Mma in this site could be re-written since most of them are from v7 and v8 :D

Answer (score 3):

Your method is fine.  It is just a little messy.  Here is my interpretation:

```
hours = 12;
radius = 1;
thetaList = Rest@Range[2 Pi, 0, -2 Pi/hours] + Pi/2;
coordinateList = radius {Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ thetaList;
Graphics[{
  FontFamily -> "Georgia",
  FontSize -> 30,
  Text ~MapThread~ {Range@hours, coordinateList},
  Circle[{0, 0}, 1.2 radius]
}]
```

[image: same output]